# Nested stdClass doesn't return expected result

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5

```
public function quickbar()
{
    $locales = config('app.locales');
    $buttons = new \stdClass;
    foreach ($locales as $locale => $language)
    {
        $buttons->$locale = new \stdClass; 
        if($this->translate($locale))
        {
            $buttons->$locale->class = "exists";
            $buttons->$locale->link = route('articles.edit', ['slug' => $this->slug, 'locale' => $locale]);
        } else {
            $buttons->$locale->class = "missing";
            $buttons->$locale->link = route('articles.create', ['slug' => $this->slug, 'locale' => $locale]);
        }

        return $buttons;
    }
}
```

In laravel 5.1 I have created the above function on my Article.php Model. The idea is that it will check if a translated version of the article exists for each supplied language.

```
$locales = config('app.locales');
```

Returns:

```
[
 "en" => "English",
 "fr" => "French",
 "nl" => "Dutch",
 "it" => "italian",
 "de" => "German",
]
```

Now the foreach loop should created a nested stdClass object for each of these languages, but I only receive En:

```
=> {#828
 +"en": {#830
   +"class": "exists",
   +"link": "http://multilingual.dev/articles/loading-efficiently/edit/en",
 },
}
```

I can't understand why I don't receive the other languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have placed your `return` in your foreach, so the loop will end after the first locale. Try to place it after the foreach.

Comment: how shameful! Thank you so much for such a stupidly simple problem. sometimes all it needs is fresh eyes!